# Is $Z$ generated by $\pm 1$ as a ring

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finitely-generated

I know that $Z$ = <$\pm 1$> as a group,$Z$ generated by $\pm 1$ as a ring. If yes, how do you show that?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't rings closed under addition?  So that's enough, isn't it?

Comment: You only need one of your two generators, not both. ${\mathbb Z} = \langle 1 \rangle$ as a group and as a ring. Also ${\mathbb Z} = \langle -1 \rangle$ as both group and ring.

Comment: In fact ${\mathbb Z}$ is generated by the empty set as a ring with $1$ (but not a s a group).

Comment: @DerekHolt Generated by the empty set??

Comment: Yes that's right. The subring generated by the empty set has to contain $0$ and $1$ in order to be a subring, so it contains all of ${\mathbb Z}$. Or to put it another way, ${\mathbb Z}$ has no subrings apart from itself.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring generated by a subset contains the additive group generated by this subset.

Comment: I should be read this way. Or ‘He who can do the more can do the least’… Sorry for the slip. Probably was thinking backwards.

Comment: No worries, just had to make sure I wasn't going crazy! +1

Answer (score 0):

$(R,..+)$ is a ring if satisfying the following three sets of axioms, called the '''ring axioms:

1. ''R'' is an [[abelian group]] under addition. In your case $\mathbb{Z}$ is.
2. ''R'' is a [[monoid]] under multiplication, meaning that:
   $$(a · b) · c = a · (b · c)$$ 
   for all $a,b,c\in R$.

There is an element 1 in R such that $a · 1 = a$ and $1 · a = a$ for all $a\in R$ (1 is the [[multiplicative identity]]).

$\color{red}{Note~ that~ the~ existence~ of~ 1~ is~ not~ assumed~ by~ some~ authors.}$

3. Multiplication is [[distributive]] with respect to addition: for all $a,b,c\in R$
   (left distributivity)
   $$a.(b+c)=(a.b)+(a.c)$$
   (right distributivity)
   $$(b+c).a=(b.a)+(c.a)$$

all the above hold in $\mathbb{Z}$. In order to show it is generated by $\pm1$ it is enough to show every elements is the sum of finitely many $\pm1$.

Comment: Why are you doing double brackets around some terms?

Comment: SorryI just want to quote them, what they are called.